# program cant start because php5ts.dll is missing

Tags: php, iis-7

I have iis 7 on windows, and installed php5.3 from windows manager.

It is not thread safe.

When I go into the command prompt and type in "php", I get that error.

This is becoming a nuseince because I am unable to install anything from the command prompt such as Pear, by typing in "php go-pear.phar" for example

How can I resolve this, thanks

Comment: Just install php with the web plattform installer..

Comment: yep ive installed php 5.3 from it, but i cant install pear from command line

Comment: Are you sure, you run the php.exe in C:\Program Files(x86)\PHP folder?

Comment: You say "it is not thread safe" but the "ts" in "php5ts.dll" stands for "thread safe" :-?

Comment: for some reason it complains when it cant find it.

Comment: everytime I execute php in the cmd , it complains.